# Sequence of actions after data connection refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data connection to an SQL database that refreshes every 15 min.

I need a sequence of actions after the data refresh.

In order:

- run main VBA code
- refresh pivot chart
- save file

I tried on the worksheet of the data:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:J2")) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If

End Sub
```

The main VBA code is in Module1. It crashes or gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: What does the main VBA code do? Is it possibly triggering the change event?

Comment: The main code will create arrays of each columns, analyse and transform it and then export it in the worksheet data for pivot chart. Is the code: ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll function is to run the main and refresh the pivot chart?